# Convert SQL query with inner, left, and nested select to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, left-join, inner-join, subquery

how can convert this query to linq?

```
SELECT p.PostID, p.PostText, p.PublishDate, u.Name
FROM AspNetUsers u INNER JOIN Posts p ON u.Id = p.PostUserID LEFT JOIN Reposts r ON p.PostID = r.PostID
WHERE p.PostUserID = 'id'
OR p.PostUserID IN ( SELECT FollowingUserID FROM Friends WHERE FollowerUserID = 'id' AND isUnfollow = 0)
OR p.PostID in (SELECT PostID FROM Reposts WHERE RepostUserID = 'id' OR RepostUserID IN ( SELECT FollowingUserID FROM Friends WHERE FollowerUserID = 'id' AND isUnfollow = 0))
ORDER BY p.PostUserID
```

Comment: the SQL query works well and it gives the required results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var results = from u in AspNetUsers
              join p in Posts on u.Id equals p.PostUserID
              join r in Reposts on p.PostId equals r.PostId into records
              from record in records.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where p.PostUserID == "id"
                 || (from friend in Friends
                     where friend.FollowerUserID == "id"
                        && friend.isUnfollow == 0
                     select friend.FollowingUserID
                    ).Contains(p.PostUserID)
                 || (from r2 in Reposts
                     where r2.RepostUserID == "id"
                        || (from friend2 in Friends
                            where friend2.FollowerUserID == "id"
                               && friend2.isUnfollow == 0
                            select friend2.FollowingUserID
                           ).Contains(r2.RepostUserID)
                     select r2.PostID
                    ).Contains(p.PostID)
              orderby p.PostUserID ascending
              select p.PostID, p.PostText, p.PublishDate, u.Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your support and time. it gives me an error in ).Contains(p.PostID) : a query body must end with a select clause or group clause